# Plotting one time-series in different colors matlab

Tags: matlab, colors, time-series, matlab-figure

I would like to reproduce the following plot in MATLAB:

[image]

For instance, consider the following time series:

```
a= [1,0.5,0.25, -0.5, -0.75,0.5,1.25, -0.8,0.1,0.2,0,3,0.8, -0.9, -1,1]
```

How can I plot values above 0 in one color and values below another color?

Comment: In your example, some points under zero are still light pink (you can see it in the beginning).

Comment: See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45505927/ploting-a-wave-with-different-colors-in-the-same-figure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The trick is to avoid the plotting of points by replacing their values by NaN.**

I suggest to first separate `a` in two arrays, lets say `a_lo` and `a_hi`.

- `a_lo` is `a` but with positive values replaced by `NaN`.
- `a_hi` is `a` but with negative values replaced by `Nan`.

So you will do something like this:

```
a_lo = a;
a_hi = a;

for i = 1:length(a)
    if a_lo(i) > 0
        a_lo(i) = NaN;
    end
    if a_hi(i) < 0
        a_hi(i) = NaN;
    end
end
```

Then you plot `a_lo` and `a_hi` with different colours, don't forget `hold on` to plot the two curves together.

```
plot(a_lo,'r'); hold on;
plot(a_hi,'b');
```

Here is an example of what I could obtain with a sine wave:

[image: sine wave]

Comment: You can do it only if you have zeros between the positive and negative numbers. This will not work on the example in the question.

Comment: @Adiel, it depends of what you mean by "work". It is true that the above zeros will not be connected to the under zeros, but I don't know if it is a requirement for OP. I just tested with the short example and it works except some points are just alone (not connected). In OP's initial curve, some points are under zero, but still light pink...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe we can use the function 'find' ? because I have a time series with 60000 data points and matlab is still busy after 5 min

Comment: @M.H I added a slight optimisation, that might reduce the time computation. You could also try with `find` indeed, to get the indexes of negative, then positive values, then replacing them by NaN, in two separate arrays.

Comment: I still think your code is completely not effective here, but if you want to improve it: `a_lo=a; a_lo(a>0)=NaN; a_hi=a; a_hi(a<0)=NaN;`

Comment: @Adiel, why do you think it would be ineffective in time series data with 60000 values?

Comment: @Bebs Thanks for the improvement. It works good even if the points passing through 0 are not displayed